# How can I change UserId in AspNet Identity Version 2 or 2.1 Alpha to an identity int

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

From what I can see there have been many posts asking how to do this but as the Identity code is changing very quickly I think most of the replies might be a bit dated. A quick searched showed me many (slightly confusing) examples. Plus I have see comments from Hao Kung which suggest things are changing and that many of the older answers may no longer be the best solutions. Quotes like this make me hope to find the **very latest** solution:

```
"This is something we didn't have time to support, but I'm looking into making 
 this easy(ier) in 1.1 right now. Hopefully something will be available in the 
 nightly builds soon."
```

For the benefit of everyone now using Identity 2 or 2 Beta could anyone point me to some steps or to links that would explain how I can change my default to an identity value? I am fairly sure this is something that a large number of people will be needing to know about so I am hoping for some very helpful answers or suggestions that could benefit the community. If possible I would really like the answer to be a Microsoft suggested solution as I realize things are still changing.  Hopefully Hao Kung could answer this question for the benefit of everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process for changing the type of the Primary Key seems to be fairly well explained in this writeup:

[Announcing RTM of ASP.NET Identity 2.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/20/test-announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-0-0.aspx)

Which also includes a link to a code sample on CodePlex:

[ASP.NET Source Code - Changing PK](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Identity/ChangePK/readme.txt)

Comment: Thank you. I will look at this link. I did review a lot of links but missed this one. Hopefully having this question will help others to find the link. I see there is now an Identity 2.1 Alpha. I wonder if anything has changed with this even more recent release.